# Theme dependent WP plugins

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am creating a WP plugin which will require either of two themes so that it can work as it’s using the theme functions inherited from either of the plugins. I wrote this conditional check.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'plugin_activation_check');

add_action ('admin_init', 'plugin_activation_check');
function plugin_activation_check()
{
 if (get_template() != 'Theme-One' || get_template() !='Theme-Two'){
        deactivate_plugins('theme-folder/my-plugin.php');

  /* message to user when they try to activate the plugin */
    wp_die('This plugin needs either Theme-One or Theme-two themes to be active.');

}
}
```

I want that the plugin can only be activated if either of two recommended themes are active. Else, deactivate that plugin and return an error message.

I can easily achieve this for one theme by writing the **if condition** like this

```
if (get_template() != 'Theme-One'){
```

But not sure how to achieve this with two themes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is your conditional will always evaluate to true.

'Theme-One' and 'Theme-Two' can't be active at the same time therefore there's a flaw in the logic. If I have 'Theme-One' active for example then `get_template() !='Theme-Two'` is true which satisfies your second condition and triggers `deactivate_plugins('theme-folder/my-plugin.php');`.

Change this:

```
if (get_template() != 'Theme-One' || get_template() !='Theme-Two'){
```

To this:

```
if ( get_template() != 'Theme-One' && get_template() !='Theme-Two' ) {
```

In the updated version we're making sure that neither theme is active.

If the number of themes is likely to grow then I'd suggest using an array instead.

Example:

```
$themes = array(
    'Theme-One',
    'Theme-Two',
    'Theme-Three',
);

if ( ! in_array( get_template(), $themes ) ) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was really stupid in making that silly mistake. I need some coffee indeed. Thanks once again.